# python: regular expressions, how to match a string of undefind length which has a structure and finishes with a specific group

Tags: python, regex

I need to create a regexp to match strings like this 999-123-222-...-22
The string can be finished by &Ns=(any number) or without this... So valid strings for me are

```
999-123-222-...-22
999-123-222-...-22&Ns=12
999-123-222-...-22&Ns=12
```

And following are not valid:

999-123-222-...-22&N=1

I have tried testing it several hours already... But did not manage to solve, really need some help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you want to literally match `999-123-22-...-22` or if that can be any sequence of numbers/dashes. Here are two different regexes:

```
/^[\d-]+(&Ns=\d+)?$/

/^999-123-222-\.\.\.-22(&Ns=\d+)?$/
```

The key idea is the `(&Ns=\d+)?$` part, which matches an optional `&Ns=<digits>`, and is **anchored** to the end of the string with `$`.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to allow strings `999-123-222-...-22` and `999-123-222-...-22&Ns=12` you better use a string function.

If you want to allow any numbers between `-` you can use the regex:

```
^(\d+-){3}[.]{3}-\d+(&Ns=\d+)?$
```

If the numbers must be of only 3 digits and the last number of only 2 digits you can use:

```
^(\d{3}-){3}[.]{3}-\d{2}(&Ns=\d{2})?$
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a phone number and extension information.. 
Why not make things simpler for yourself (and anyone who has to read this later) and split the input rather than use a complicated regex?

```
s = '999-123-222-...-22&Ns=12'
parts = s.split('&Ns=') # splits on Ns and removes it
```

If the piece before the "&" is a phone number, you could do another split and get the area code etc into separate fields, like so:

```
phone_parts = parts[0].split('-') # breaks up the digit string and removes the '-'
area_code = phone_parts[0]
```

The portion found after the the optional '&Ns=' can be checked to see if it is numeric with the string method isdigit, which will return true if all characters in the string are digits and there is at least one character, false otherwise.

```
if len(parts) > 1:
    extra_digits_ok = parts[1].isdigit()
```